# Can anyone explain how the below LUA code works?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, lua

I am using nginx with lua . To access my ES cluster i am configuring with lua code . I want to know how the code works..

```
-- get URL
local uri = ngx.var.uri

-- get method
local method = ngx.req.get_method()

local allowed  = false

for path, methods in pairs(restrictions[role]) do
  -- path matched rules?
  local p = string.match(uri, path)

  -- method matched rules?
  local m = nil
  for _, _method in pairs(methods) do
    m = m and m or string.match(method, _method)
  end

  if p and m then
    allowed = true
    break
  end
end

if not allowed then
  return write403Message()
end
```

Let be the `URL: http://localhost/_GET`,`method:GET`, `path:/_GET`
Then

```
local p = string.match(uri, path) -->Then p variable has value GET(i.e p=GET)
```

Correct me if i am wrong?

```
for _, _method in pairs(methods) do
        m = m and m or string.match(method, _method)
      end
```

what the above snippet will do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you refer to the Lua reference manual if you want to know what the code does:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match

If you want to know what string.match returns in your example you can use the print function.

For example:

```
p = string.match(uri, path)
print(p)
```

For your example:

> Let be the URL: http://localhost/_GET,method:GET, path:/_GET Then
>
> local p = string.match(uri, path) -->Then p variable has value GET(i.e
>   p=GET)

`p` will acutally refer to `"/_GET"`

/_GET is your pattern. string.match will return the match which for this simple dinstinct pattern is just the pattern itself.

If you would for example request a match to any number for example you would get the actual number from the string.